# How can I tell when I logged into Windows?

Tags: windows, login, cygwin, wtmp

On UNIX I can tell when I logged in and out of my workstation with the last command.  Is there a way to get the same information on my Windows workstation?

I notice that Cygwin has a last command, but wtmp doesn't seem to be populated.  Is there a way to get last working with Cygwin?

(If this can only be done programmatically, should the question be on StackOverflow?)

Comment: This question is fine for SuperUser.

Answer (score 20):

You can try "net user < username >" - one of the many results will be the 'Last logon' time (note: I've only tried this on a domain workstation, not a standalone one, so your results may be slightly different).

Comment: you have to add `/domain` to the command, if you're on a domain...

Comment: ahah! in that case, my check of the local user worked perfectly. cheers

Answer (score 14):

Open Command Prompt.
at prompt, type 'quser' should display your logon username and time along with some other data.

Comment: The simplest thing I found here, and that works! Thanks. Stuns me that this isn't more easily available on the start menu somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I see a lot of dancing around the event log answer, but not the exact answer, so I will give it.

1. Go into the Event Viewer
2. Expand Windows Logs (under Event Viewer)
3. Choose Security (under Windows Logs)
4. View the Task Category column for logons
5. Click on a logon row and view the details to see if it is the user you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy, there is a bunch of audits you can set up including Logon and Logoff.

After setting this up (and performing a restart), all the details should appear in the event log.

Comment: Good idea, though it requires Administrative rights (or authorization to change such settings).

Comment: This is also not a solution if the OP wants to know *NOW* when he last logged on, *before* he configured auditing.

Comment: I have a Dutch Windows, so I can't search on "Local Security Policy", and when I launch "secpol.msc", it is not found. I have a Windows-10 Home Edition. Is this not covered here?

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you: [Last login time in VBScript](http://techtasks.com/code/viewbookcode/867)?

Comment: It's better to post more than just the link (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15625/is-downvoting-link-only-answers-acceptable)

Comment: I don't personally mind a link-answer, as long as I don't have to click it to understand what it is. "Does this work for you" doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: especially since links like that tend to eventually break

Answer (score -1):

you can check the **windows events logs** http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308427 for that!

Comment: And more precisely, what to check ? Because the event logs tells a lot of things.

Comment: unfortunately even MS breaks older links nowadays without any remorse